# query in mysql select with string variable

Tags: php, mysql

**Error Output**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '//some values
```

I have a query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE col1 = " . $row['value'] . "";
```

But if did my query hard code like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE col1 = 'string data (string data too)'";
```

it works as I expected.

Note that I have some values that has **( )** *open and close parenthesis* like I put in hard coded query above.

Also Note that **`$row['value']`** returns correct value like I tested in the hardcoded query.

I am expecting the same output as in hardcoded query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this query has a string data then it must be enclosed by quotes `'` like as follow.check this query once.

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE col1 = '" . $row['value'] . "'";
```

Comment: But it would be better to used prepared statements, no?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes bro but there he has an error I try to solve the error there.I also aware of the thing gone used for security.

Comment: A.) not your bro and 2.) we should not be teaching dangerous methods of coding.

Comment: hmm, i 'll keep that in practice.

Comment: @addy, thanks it works.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, thanks for the great suggestion about prepared statements. I will explore it.